# L20n get translated string in javascript

Tags: javascript, web-applications, translation, l20n

Is there a way of quickly grabbing translated string in javascript?

For example like this:
var s = L20n.get("hello");

I am using 3.5 from npm.

Following does not work:

```
document.l10n.ready.then(function(context) {
    document.l10n.formatValue('myItemKey').then(function(result){
        console.log(result);
    });
});
```

It results in printing item key instead of translated value.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using version 3.x, use `formatValue`:

```
document.l10n.formatValue('hello').then(console.log);
```

You can read more about it here: https://github.com/l20n/l20n.js/blob/v3.x/docs/view.md#viewformatvalueid-args.  `document.l10n` is an instance of the `View` class that is created automatically for you when the page loads.

The method is asynchronous so that you don't have to worry about race conditions related to language files not being loaded yet.

Comment: BTW. don't you think that using a promise to get a simple value is too much?

It should be simple like 

    var translated = document.l10n.get('myItemKey');